# How do I make sorting work?

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation, iron-router

The pub/sub to pull all posts (geo tagged) within a certain distance is not working. The aim is to get user's current location and then use the pub (server calculation) to pull the relevant data + use sort on router to sort it.

**Helpers/ Events in js** (This portion, Im still tweaking it to see what works)

```
Template.postsList.onCreated(function() {
  this.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function (){
    var currentLocation = Geolocation.latLng();
      if(currentLocation) {
        Session.set('currentLocation', currentLocation); 
      }
    }, 2000
  );   
  Session.set('postSubmitErrors', {});
});

Template.postsList.helpers({
  loc : function () { 
    return Session.get('currentLocation');... // may not be needed if get in router

Template.postsList.events({
  postsByDistance : function() {  // may not be needed if get in router
    var loc = Session.get('currentLocation');...
```

**The error given in the terminal is**

> Exception from sub postsByDistance id bsWXKgw5QboNzCRXw Error:
>   Exception while polling query
>   {"collectionName":"posts","selector":{"loc":{"$near":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":{"currentLocation":{"lat":xxx,"lng":xxx}}},"$maxDistance":500}}},"options":{"transform":null}}:
>   $near requires a point, given { type: "Point", coordinates: {
>   currentLocation: { lat: xxx, lng: xxx } } }

If I change pub line to [anything.lng, anything.lat] it says lat or lng of undefined
Occasionally I get a `Exception while polling query meteor` error when I change the argument in the `function()`.

**16 Aug 15 - Updates after suggestions:** 
**new pub**

```
  Posts._ensureIndex({'loc' : '2dsphere'});  

  Meteor.publish('postsByDistance', function(options) {     
    check(options, Object);                          
    return Posts.find({
      loc: { 
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type:        "Point", 
            coordinates: [currentLocation.lng, currentLocation.lat]
```

Error now says currentLocation is not defined. But I did define in the helper?
I also think within the error it says I have `"options":{"transform":null}}` which if correct is not supposed to appear?

Comment: From the error you posted it seems that you're passing and object as the value for `coordinates`. Shouldn't you instead use an array with two number values?

Comment: @apendua I tried to pass it with currentLocation which is defined as = geolocation.latlng() which should return an array. Could you maybe suggest how I may troubleshoot or test for errors? Any sample codes would be great too

Answer (score 1):

In your mongo query the `coordinates` field should be definitely an array containing two numbers. But as I understand that's something you've already tried. It didn't work for a different reason.

It looks like your problem is caused by a simple "race condition". Namely, the first time you're subscribing to `postsByDistance` the session variable `currentLocation` is not yet set and that's the reason you may be getting `undefined` values for latitude and longitude.

Also - it's probably a typo error - looking at your code you pass an object with `currentLocation` filed to subscription. On the other hand in your corresponding publish function you are referring to the whole thing as `currentLocation` but it should be

```
 currentLocation.currentLocation.lng
 currentLocation.currentLocation.lat
```

with your current variables setup. I suggest you change those names because it may lead to a lot of unwanted errors.

Comment: So I suppose it should be [cl.cl.lng, cl.cl.lat] format? Do I need to change anything in the helper file? How should I change the naming formats?

Comment: Naming formats are fine, I was only referring to the first argument of your publish function. Having it named `currentLocation` is misleading because what you really have is an `options` object with a `currentLocation` field.

Comment: I have updated and new error appears despite it being cl.cl.lat/lng or cl.lat/lng. Any idea how else i should test it? No error showing up on browser. Also says currentLocation is not defined. (ive tagged the error lines above)

Comment: As I said before, this happening because `Session.get('currentLocation')` will return `undefined` for the first time you call it. You need a conditional statement either on client (before `Meteor.subscribe`) or on the server (inside the publish function) to make sure your application can handle that edge case. I would suggest doing this both on client and server actually.